# pycham autocomplete not doing its job

Tags: autocomplete, pycharm

as a new student using pycham doing django project, I have hell of time typing almost every keywords manually, I have auto complete option checked in setting but still tons of keywords wont show up!

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/")
static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
.
.
.
```

none of them showed up on my first typing, some of them showing after first used, how to get pycham to show every possible keywords as I type anytime, even its a first use?  tyvm

Comment: Dude i had the same problem I don't think that the autocomplete is the best in the community edition, I bought it and everything works like a charm

Comment: Community Edition does not have support for Django, consider using Professional Edition.